# Error in fetching product details from API

Tags: javascript, html, css, fetch-api

I have been trying to figure out the reason behind what could be wrong exactly.

The basic HTML and CSS have been pre-written, but JavaScript is used to create the core elements (or items) meant to populate the DOM.

In my script, I am trying to fetch product information to populate the browser interface with shopping items.

The error that I am getting in the console is: ***Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'innerText')***

```js
async function fakeStoreAPI_Products () {
    const urlOfData = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
    if(urlOfData.status !== 200 || !urlOfData.ok){
        throw new Error('There was a problem fetching the data...')
    }else if(urlOfData.status === 200 && urlOfData.ok){
        const response = await urlOfData.json();
        populate(response)
    }
}

function populate (completeData) {
    const displayAllCardsHere = document.getElementById('cards_inner');    
    const data = completeData;
    
    for(const datum of data){
        // The parent
        const div_class_card = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'card')
        // Child [p_class_title]
        const p_class_title = document.createElement('p').setAttribute('class', 'title')
        // Child [img]
        const img = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'img')
        // Child [p_class_description]
        const p_class_description = document.createElement('p').setAttribute('class', 'description')
        // Child [div_class_cat_price] ~ With children
        const div_class_cat_price = document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'cat_price')
        // Children of [div_class_cat_price] ~ decendants of [div_class_card ~ The [grand] parent]
        const p_class_category = document.createElement('p').setAttribute('class', 'category')
        const p_class_price = document.createElement('p').setAttribute('class', 'price')
        
        p_class_title.innerText = datum['title']
        img.innerText = datum['image']
        p_class_description.innerText = datum['description']
        p_class_category.innerText = datum['category']
        p_class_price.innerText = datum['price']
        
        div_class_card.append(p_class_title)
        div_class_card.append(img)
        div_class_card.append(p_class_description)
        
        div_class_card.append(div_class_cat_price)
        
        div_class_cat_price.append(p_class_category)
        div_class_cat_price.append(p_class_price)
        
        displayAllCardsHere.append(div_class_card)
    }
}

fakeStoreAPI_Products().catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

```css
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    font-family: Nunito Sans, Yu Gothic UI;
}

div#cards_outer{
    width: 100%;
    padding: 20px;
    display: grid;
    grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

div#heading{
    text-align: center;
}

div#heading span{
    font-size: 40px;
    font-weight: 600;
    /* hori verti blur colour */
    text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #0007;
}

div#cards_inner{
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 1fr / repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
    grid-gap: 20px;
}

div#cards_inner div.card{
    /* hori verti blur color */
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    padding: 10px;
}

div#cards_inner div.card img{
    width: 100%;
}

div#cards_inner div.card p.description{
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: justify;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}

div#cards_inner div.card p.title,
div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.category,
div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.price{
    text-align: center;
}

div#cards_inner div.card p.title{
    font-size: 18px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-transform: capitalize;
}

div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.category,
div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.price{
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: 600;
}

div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.category{
    text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Nunito+Sans&display=swap" />
    <title>Fetch data from API and display data on the browser</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="cards_outer">
        <div id="heading"><span>Fake API Store</span></div>
        <div id="cards_inner">
            <!-- populate cards here -->
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

What exactly did I miss?

Comment: Which line specifically does the error point to? Since you have         `p_class_title.innerText`, `img.innerText`, `p_class_description.innerText`, `p_class_category.innerText` and `p_class_price.innerText` in your code, it is unclear which one specifically gives you trouble.

Comment: If you try commenting any of those lines, you will see the error on the next line after the one commented.

Comment: It says something is "undefined"

Comment: Please don't edit your question so that the original problem disapears

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is, that you set the variable to `document.createElement('div').setAttribute('class', 'title')`, but `setAttribute('class', 'title')` doesn't return the created HTML element.

You should do it like this:

```
// The parent
const div_class_card = document.createElement('div')
div_class_card.setAttribute('class', 'card')
// Child [p_class_title]
const p_class_title = document.createElement('p')
p_class_title.setAttribute('class', 'title')
// Child [img]
const img = document.createElement('img')
img.setAttribute('class', 'img')
// Child [p_class_description]
const p_class_description = document.createElement('p')
p_class_description.setAttribute('class', 'description')
// Child [div_class_cat_price] ~ With children
const div_class_cat_price = document.createElement('div')
div_class_cat_price.setAttribute('class', 'cat_price')
// Children of [div_class_cat_price] ~ decendants of [div_class_card ~ The [grand] parent]
const p_class_category = document.createElement('p')
p_class_category.setAttribute('class', 'category')
const p_class_price = document.createElement('p')
p_class_price.setAttribute('class', 'price')
```

First create the element and set the variable for it, then use the variable to set attributes.

**Edit:**

The image is not shown, because you create a div element in your `img` variable. And div elements don't handle src attributes. It should work, if you do the following:

```
// Child [img]
const img = document.createElement('img')
img.setAttribute('class', 'img')
```

Also, you are using the string `'datum["image"]'` as the src attribute. It should be the following.

```
img.setAttribute('src', datum["image"])
```

Comment: OMG! You got it! (By the way I edited the question because the p_class... variables and the img variable should have been 'p' & 'img' tags respectively). This is the correction I just made.

Comment: Please can you re-edit your answer again using my correction?  Please?

Comment: So far images are the only things not showing... hmm...

Comment: I tried using the img.src = datum['image'] but it is not displaying

Comment: Please edit your question and add the part about the image not working, including what `datum['image']` contains.

Comment: Uh oh... There are some issues in your answer which I already corrected in the question.

Comment: First of all, I want to say a very big thank you in advance for going through the undeserved pain of helping me out. I have re-edited the question. Try running the snippet

Comment: Images are missing

Comment: You were born to solve problems. Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 0):

My preference is use HTML for HTML and then use javascript to manipulate/populate the HTML. From your code, the internal structure of your card is not immediately obvious. Use the `<template>` tag to structure your card. Then use javascript to populate a clone of the template, then add that to the DOM.

Not only do I find it easier to work with HTML as HTML, this also results in simpler javascript.

```js
/*Nothing has changed here, move along*/
async function fakeStoreAPI_Products() {
  const urlOfData = await fetch('https://fakestoreapi.com/products');
  if (urlOfData.status !== 200 || !urlOfData.ok) {
    throw new Error('There was a problem fetching the data...')
  } else if (urlOfData.status === 200 && urlOfData.ok) {
    const response = await urlOfData.json();
    populate(response)
  }
}

function populate(completeData) {
  const displayAllCardsHere = document.getElementById('cards_inner');
  //Get the template object
  const template = document.getElementById("cardTemplate");  
  const data = completeData;  
  
  for (const datum of data) {
     //Clone the template
    let clone = template.content.cloneNode(true);
    /*Use query selectors to populate the clone*/
    clone.querySelector(".title").innerText = datum["title"];
    clone.querySelector(".img img").setAttribute("src", datum["image"]);
    clone.querySelector(".description").innerText = datum["description"];
    clone.querySelector(".cat_price .category").innerText = datum["category"];
    clone.querySelector(".cat_price .price").innerText = datum["price"];
    
    //Append clone to the DOM
    displayAllCardsHere.appendChild(clone);
  }
}

fakeStoreAPI_Products().catch((err) => {
  console.log(err)
})
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: Nunito Sans, Yu Gothic UI;
}

div#cards_outer {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  display: grid;
  grid-row-gap: 20px;
}

div#heading {
  text-align: center;
}

div#heading span {
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 600;
  /* hori verti blur colour */
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 6px #0007;
}

div#cards_inner {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 1fr / repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 20px;
}

div#cards_inner div.card {
  /* hori verti blur color */
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  padding: 10px;
}

div#cards_inner div.card img {
  width: 100%;
}

div#cards_inner div.card p.description {
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: justify;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

div#cards_inner div.card p.title,
div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.category,
div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.price {
  text-align: center;
}

div#cards_inner div.card p.title {
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: capitalize;
}

div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.category,
div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.price {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

div#cards_inner div.card div.cat_price p.category {
  text-transform: capitalize;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards_outer">
  <div id="heading"><span>Fake API Store</span></div>
  <div id="cards_inner">
    <!-- populate cards here -->
  </div>
</div>
<template id="cardTemplate">
  <div class="card">
      <p class="title"></p>
      <div class="img"><img src=""/></div>
      <div class="description"></div>
      <div class="cat_price">
        <p class="category"></p>
        <p class="price"></p>        
      </div>
  </div>
</template>
```